# Add ath10k_pci to ubuntu 18.04 minimal cd installer

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I want to re-install on my laptop using minimal cd to avoid all the bloated and unnecessary software that makes my laptop runs slow.
I copied the iso on a USB stick and the installer runs, but the problem is there is no driver for my "Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377" wifi card. I don't have access to a wired connection. Where i live there aren't wired connections and i can't buy a router/modem because i use an unlimited 4g hotspot. So the only option i have is to use WiFi.
How can i add ath10k drivers for QCA9377 on the ubuntu minimal cd ?
I looked into the usb stick but there is no lib folder, no usr folder, just a bunch of files i don't understand.

Thanks very much.

Comment: why not download the DEB package when you download the ISO and then add it afterwards?

Comment: i cannot install the minima ubuntu without a internet connection, and i can't connect without the driver